# Does this picture represent anything mathematically?

Tags: pi

This image here shows a beautiful fractal-like image. Does this map some sort of function, each number corresponding to a section/colour? Or is this just pretty art? Thanks!

[image: Pi?]

Comment: It looks like a network plot.  There are many nodes on the perimeter and the color curves are the links between nodes.  A computer visualization program can plot them.

Comment: Yes, that circles with a lot of internal arcs look cool. Also it represents the duality of man and the futility of human endeavor.

Comment: Where did this image come from? The context could be helpful, and anyway, sources should be credited.

Comment: @NateEldredge My friend sent it to me >_< I don't know where he got it.

Comment: I found this for you. I searched for this thread. This video has the answer for your question  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NPoj8lk9Fo4

Comment: I strongly disagree with the close vote. I found the following in the help center: "Solving mathematical puzzles" is on-topic. This indeed was a mathematical puzzle to me, so I wonder: Was this help center topic overlooked by all five users?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This image represents the progression of the first $10,000$ digits of $\pi$, and was produced by Cristian Ilies Vasile using the software Circos (or so a Google search tells me).

To elaborate on this, since $\pi$ begins $3.14159\ldots$, you would begin to form this image by first adding an edge/arc from $3$ to $1$, then $1$ to $4$, then $4$ to $1$, and so on.

You can see this image as related to the question of if $\pi$ is a [normal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number), which is still unknown.  Roughly speaking, a number is normal if it's digit progressions of all lengths are 'random,' in the sense that all finite digit progressions of a given length occur with equal frequency.  For this image, that would mean that there are a roughly equal number of edges leading from any one node to any other node (and also from any node to itself, but I don't see those edges drawn).

Answer (score 7):

The method used to generate this image using the digits of $\pi$ is described [here.](http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/pi/art/method.mhtml)

I disagree with your characterization of the image as "fractal-like".

Comment: Fractal-like, meaning, it is reminiscent of a fractal for me, not necessarily a fractal.